# How can I select a process model for an existing project in Azure DevOps Server

Tags: azure-devops-server-2019, processmodel

I have an existing project that has been migrated over time through several versions of TFS and most recently to Azure DevOps Server 2019 (17.153.29522.3) (Update 1.1) (on-premise).  Up to this point I have just been using TFVC but I am interested in starting to use work items to track bugs / issues / etc.  With this in mind I am looking to select a process model for my project (I'm thinking the 'Basic' process model would probably be adequate for my needs) but just can't seem to figure out how to do it.  I've read a number of how-to posts but none really seem to align with what I'm seeing.  Any guidance on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to select the process before you create a new team project. Now you can use existing work item types in your team project. If you want to change the process, you have to edit work item types, their fields, and workflow with [Process Template Editor](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=KarthikBalasubramanianMSFT.TFSProcessTemplateEditor).